# How to unset and remove blank options from a submitted drop down menu?

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my code to use [Condorcet](https://github.com/julien-boudry/Condorcet):

```
use CondorcetPHP\Condorcet\Condorcet;
use CondorcetPHP\Condorcet\Election;
use CondorcetPHP\Condorcet\Candidate;
use CondorcetPHP\Condorcet\CondorcetUtil;
use CondorcetPHP\Condorcet\Vote;

if (isset($_POST) && $_POST != "") {
    
Condorcet::setDefaultMethod('Schulze');
$election = new Election ();

print("<pre>");
print_r($_POST['item']);

// To get Candidates by Category via Doctrine orm
$category = $em->getRepository('Entities\Category')->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
$candidates = $category->getCandidates();

$total_items = 0;
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
         $candidate = $candidate->getCandidate();
         $election->addCandidate(new Candidate($candidate));
         ++$total_items;
}

$votes = array();
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $item => $ranking) {
    $vote_factor = 1 + $total_items - $ranking;
    if (isset($votes[$vote_factor])) {
       $votes[$vote_factor] = (array) $votes[$vote_factor];
       $votes[$vote_factor][] = $item;
    } else {
       $votes[$vote_factor] = $item;
    }
}    

$result = $election->addVote(new Vote($votes));  

print("<br />");
foreach ($election->getResult('Schulze') as $rank => $candidates) :
    echo 'Rank ' . $rank . ': ';
    echo implode(', ', $candidates);
    echo '<br />';
endforeach;

print_r($result->getSimpleRanking()); // To be saved in db.
echo 'Schulze winner is : ' . $election->getWinner('Schulze')->getName() . '<br />';
}

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
        Wingspan: <select name="item[Wingspan]" id="Wingspan">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                 </select><br />
        Scythe:  <select name="item[Scythe]" id="Scythe">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                 </select><br />
        Spirit Island: <select name="item[Spirit Island]" id="Spirit Island">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                  </select><br />
        Everdell: <select name="item[Everdell]" id="Everdell">
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                  </select><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add a blank select option, that my users if they don't want to have some candidates in voting just use the blank select option and don't be forced to select a ranking number from the drop down menu. How to omit blank options completely from listing and voting? I think I have to unset blank options in a foreach? If yes, how?

Comment: Unrelated, but I suggest you never use name or id=submit if you ever want to submit using script